# Can I run a Ruby app with RubyMine on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I am currently using windows and the RubyMine IDE. I was given a ruby on rails application to run, the problem is i am not really familiar with ruby and I was wondering if I could import the app into the IDE and run it, just to test it on my browser. Any help on this?

Answer (score 5):

Simply open the folder with RubyMine. It will detect the Rails application and prompt you for some instructions.

There are two gotchas:

1. Windows is not the best environment to run a Rails application. It might not work if you have dependencies that require to be compiled.
2. If the Rails version is too old, RubyMine might not be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Simone. I'm also using RubyMine with Windows. I'm assuming that your ruby on rails environment is properly set up.

To import a project, I've found that creating a new project with the same name as the app to be imported will prompt RubyMine to ask you if you'd rather import the new project instead. If you import, you'll be able to run your RoR app locally using a local WEBrick server (default url should be http://localhost:3000).